# Show Chrome desktop notifications only when tab is inactive

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm currently using the following code to show Desktop notifications in Google Chrome:

```
new Notification(data.sender.displayName, {
                    icon: '/images/logo.png',
                    body: data.content,
});
```

This is for a chat application and it doesn't make sense to show notifications on the same page as the chat. How can I make it so that the notification only appears when the tab is inactive or if the window is out of focus?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API) to find out if the window is visible. You can use event listeners to set custom hide/unhide events. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/#1060034).